# What is the difference between derivability and provability?

Tags: logic, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I am reading Lof's Intuitionistic type theory. He says,

`.. intuitionistically, truth is identified with provability, though of course not (because of Godel’s incompleteness theorem) with derivability within any particular formal system`

I am not sure if i understand this right, I have been thinking provability and derivability are same notions and Godel's theorem applies to both. Can someone explain me how they are different notions?

I also read somewhere that, derivability is syntactic while provability is more meta level. I dont think i understand that either.

Comment: I believe the idea is that "provability" is meant in an informal sense - that is, something is true if it has a "satisfying" proof. In particular, nothing should be "true for no reason." And "derivability" is the formal counterpart - that is, provability *in some formal system*. I am not sure this is accurate, though, which is why I'm leaving this as a comment as opposed to an answer.

Comment: Thanks, and he says something about structural induction, not sure how it could be related in informal sense http://hub.darcs.net/co-dan/website/browse/notes/derivability-vs-provability.md

Comment: Incidentally, his last name is Martin-Löf, not just Löf.

Comment: It is common in proof theory to use the word "proof" to refer to a natural-language argument (e.g. about proof theory) and the word "derivation" to refer to a formal proof in a particular system. The quote is using the terms in a similar way.

Answer (score 4):

See [The Development of Intuitionistic Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionistic-logic-development/) : the "natural" semantics for intuitionistic logic is based on *proof* (or *construction*) instead of *truth*.

Thus, it is in some way an "undefined" concept.

In the context of a formalization of [Intuitionistic Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/), the concept of *derivation* is relative to a *calculus*, and it is defined as usual as a sequence of formulae, "derived" by way of application of the allowed rules of inferences from axioms or assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't understand. What is a proof without a derivation? These terms mean the same thing to me. And in your answer you write "proof ... instead of *truth*". That's different from what Martin-Löf says, which is "truth is identified with provability."

Comment: @MaxHeiber - *derivability* is the formal "model" of proof defined in modern mathematical logic. "proof" was the general mathematical tool: Euclid's *Elements* is made of proofs but no formalized derivations.