# Differentiability of the Riemann function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, riemann-zeta, riemann-integration

I have defined the function $\zeta : (1, +\infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as:
$$\zeta(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^x}$$

I have to study the differentiability of this function. I have tried to use the theorem that allows you to swap summation and derivative, but I don't know how to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} g'(x)$ converges uniformly, necessary to use the theorem, where $g(x) := \frac{1}{n^x}$

Comment: Since we have restricted the dominion of the function to an interval of $\mathbb{R}$, we are trying to study its derivability (which is essentialy the differentiability, but just to make it clear).

Comment: Only "essentially"? What do you mean by "derivability", if it is different from "differentiability"? See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519481/what-is-the-difference-between-derivability-and-provability).

Comment: Is this a tripos q?

Comment: What's a tripos q?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\zeta(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}$ be a series representation for the Riemann-Zeta Function for $x\in (1,\infty)$.

Let $z'(x)$ be the series of the differentiated terms of the Riemann Zeta function so that

$$z'(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log(n)}{n^x}\tag 1$$

for $x\in(1,\infty)$.  For all $\delta>1$, the series in $(1)$ converges uniformly for $x\ge \delta$.

Therefore, for all $x\ge \delta>1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\zeta'(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^x}\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log(n)}{n^x}\tag2
\end{align}$$

Since the equality in $(2)$ is true for all $x\ge \delta>1$, then we have

$$\zeta'(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log(n)}{n^x}$$

for all $x>1$.  And we are done!

Comment: Thank you! But, how we can prove that For all δ>1, the series in (1) converges uniformly for x≥δ?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Clearly $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log(n)}{n^x}\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log(n)}{n^\delta}<\infty$.  So, by the [Weierstrass M-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test#Statement), we have UC on $[\delta,\infty)$

Comment: Sorry, but I can't prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{log(n)}{n^ \delta}$  < $\infty$, I tried with D'Alembert criterion with no result. Excuse my awkwardness

Comment: Note that for any $\alpha>0$ we have$$\log(n)<n \implies \log(n^\alpha)=\alpha \log(n)<n^\alpha\implies \log(n)<\frac{n^\alpha}{\alpha}$$Take any $0< \alpha<\delta -1$, say $\alpha = \frac12(\delta -1)$.  Now can you conclude?

Comment: Perfect! Now it's done. Thank you very much, without that hint I couldn't have got it.

Comment: Excellent!  Pleased to hear that this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way that can be used if you know the theory of complex variables.

Let $C$ be a counterclockise-oriented circle in $\mathbb C$ within the half-plane $\operatorname{Re} z>1.$ Then

\begin{align}
& \int_C \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^z} \, dz \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_C \frac{dz}{n^z} \text{ by Fubini's theorem, which can} \\
& \text{be applied since } z\mapsto\frac 1 {n^z} \text{ is continuous on the} \\
& \text{compact set }C \\[8pt]
= {} & \sum_{n=1}^\infty 0 = 0.
\end{align}
The conclusion then follows by Morera's theorem.