# Prove zeta function has coninuous derivatives of all orders

Tags: real-analysis, summation, riemann-zeta, riemann-sum, zeta-functions

I need to prove that the $\zeta$ function $$\zeta(x):=\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^x}$$defines a function that has continuous derivatives of all orders.

Here's my attempt:

So, the $n$'th derivative is $$\frac{(-1)^n\ln^n(k)}{k^x}$$

So, we can see that this is continuous on $x\in(1,\infty)$ and that the partial sums $\zeta_s(x)=\sum^s_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^n\ln^n(k)}{k^x}$ are finite, so hence the function has continuous derivates of all orders.

Is this enough/correct?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2804445/differentiability-of-the-riemann-function). Since they are differentiable they are continuous, too.

Comment: @DietrichBurde no it doesn't

Comment: the second post you provided gives an explanation whether it converges uniformly

Comment: As the duplicate says, it doesn't converge uniformly on $E$, but it converges normally on every $[a,+\infty)$ with $a > 1$. So it has continuous derivatives of all orders.

Comment: @DietrichBurde ok, so if it converges, this means it's continuous?okay thank you, i get it